# How to support workday app with multiple docusign esignature accounts?

Tags: docusignapi, account, workday-api

Workday supports the use of only 1 Docusign esignature Account Integration key to be configured in their system/tenant. However I need to understand from DocuSign community if there is a way to link multiple docusign integration key/account to the same Workday tenant using a custom integration. This way the documents from workday can be published into the respective docusign accounts for e signature (based on the geographic location)... Any ideas and experience on this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your benefit and everyone else, there's a confusion I'd like to make sure is cleared.

DocuSign has **Accounts** and **Integrations Keys**.

**Accounts**

Represents a tenant in the DocuSign cloud with one or more users. Users of the account can use many apps that each have a different integration key if they consent to them.

**Integration Key**

Represent an integration (or an app) and while the developer who created it had to use an account to get it going - any DocuSign account can use it as long as they consent.

So it's a many-to-many relationship and a completely different thing. The workday app has a single Integration Key but it can be used with many different accounts.

Comment: thank you. I can add only 1 account in the workday tenant. Ie Workday can point to only 1 Docusign account. Thats the problem statement.

Comment: did you write the WorkDay app? I assume not. Posting here is not going to be very helpful, you may need to talk to the developers who built it, or contact support.